# Tridion UGC doesn't save anything in database

Tags: content-delivery, ugc

I'm trying to configure Tridion for User Generated content following the instructions from the installation manual and from the sdllivecontent website. Still, I am not able to make it works. Nothings happens on the database side.

In the CM GUI side, when I'm trying to manually add a comment to a component I get the following error "Saving comment failed", but I don't find any more information in the Tridion logs, either in the UGC web service log that at least could give me some clues about the problem. Previously, I properly (I think) configured UGC Web service end points in the DataSource.xml file.

In the website side, I have a page with the comment server control and with the rating server control (published with default UGC TBB and properly deployed). When I try to save a comment or a rate in this page, nothing happens, no exceptions, no errors. Either in the UGC web service log (logback is set to ALL).

The UGC web service seems to works OK. I could check it via browser and through VS IDE. It seems to respond correctly to queries. Maybe the problem come from the storage configuration in the UGC web service, but I can't find it.

I am also using the AllowAnonymousPostClaimProcessor. I have it on both the website and UGC web service.

Anybody any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to take it slowly and test first with saving comments from the GUI. Step 1: save a comment for a page in the GUI. Step 2: check the UGC WebService logs and check if anything is logged at current time. If nothing is there then you need to remove the WebDav handler from your UGC WebService webApp. If something is logged but it seems to just hang then make sure you have jsoup.jar in your lib folder.

Comment: Daniel, you are right! Seems like I forgot this one. This is properly documented in [sdllivecontent](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=InstallingUGCServerRoleAsADotNETWapp.xml&docid=task_9FD11192A9094CCFA827ED66AC0AC4C8) website. Now, I want to make some more testing with the UGC logging enabled and see if I can find the problem in log file. But this just saved me so much time. Thanks!

Comment: Well, with the UGC logging enabled... really I don't see any error message, but the classpath contains the missing jar (jsoup) that in fact could be a clue to find the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe Daniel Neagu could post it as an answer and you could accept it? For future reference...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take it slowly and test first with saving comments from the GUI.

1. Save a comment for a page in the GUI.
2. Check the UGC WebService logs and check if anything is logged at current time.

   1. If nothing is there, you need to remove the WebDav handler from your UGC WebService webApp.
   2. If something is logged but it seems to just hang, make sure you have jsoup.jar in your lib folder.